# How to repeat executing a group elements in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a problem. I am new to jQuery, and do not understand how can I repeat of my created animation. Here example of my code:

```
$("#text_rotator1_1").fadeIn(3000,function(){
    $("#text_rotator1_2").fadeIn(3000, function(){
        $("#text_rotator1_3").fadeIn(3000, function() {
            $("#text_rotator1_4").fadeIn(3000, function() {
            $("#text_rotator1_1").fadeOut(1000);
            $("#text_rotator1_2").fadeOut(1000);
            $("#text_rotator1_3").fadeOut(1000);
            $("#text_rotator1_4").fadeOut(1000, function() {

            });

            });
        });
    });
});
```

When all 4 elements are faded out, then I want to repeat fade in all elements. Like some while cycle... I think, you understand me :)

Comment: Do you want them to fade out at the same time or one after another like you code illistrates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap it inside a function, and call that function as your last callback:

```
function start(){
$("#text_rotator1_1").fadeIn(3000,function(){
    $("#text_rotator1_2").fadeIn(3000, function(){
        $("#text_rotator1_3").fadeIn(3000, function() {
            $("#text_rotator1_4").fadeIn(3000, function() {
            $("#text_rotator1_1").fadeOut(1000);
            $("#text_rotator1_2").fadeOut(1000);
            $("#text_rotator1_3").fadeOut(1000);
            $("#text_rotator1_4").fadeOut(1000, start);

            });
        });
    });
});
}
start();
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/BYRkp/

Comment: Just beat me to it! I wrote the fiddle and all too!

Comment: Thaaaaaaaaaaanks :) You are my Hero, Niklas :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess i'd do something like this, using custom events:

```
$('.text_rotators').bind('fadeMeIn',function(){
  $(this).fadeIn("slow",function(){
      $(this).trigger('fadeMeOut');
  });
}).bind('fadeMeOut',function(){
      $(this).fadeOut("slow",function(){
      $(this).trigger('fadeMeIn');
  });
});

$('.text_rotators').trigger('fadeMeIn');
```

Comment: To pixeline, maybe this method is more practical, abstract... but for a while, for me this to hard ;) But thanks, I think, I will try it too ;)

Comment: custom events are not that hard once you understand the concept. What if in addition to the usual "click", "mouseover", ... events, you could create your own? With jquery it's dead simple. simply use bind(), give it a name, what it should do. Then, when you actually need it, .trigger() it.